# NodeJS socket.io room & broadcast issue

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I don't know if it's a bug or if I'm doing something wrong but if i broadcast more than one message, only the first message is broadcasted to the right room, all others are broadcasted to everyone connected to the socket.io.

```
socket.on('clientMessage', function(content){
    socket.emit('serverMessage', {name : 'You said', data : content} );
    socket.get('username', function(err, username){
        if (err) { throw err; }         
        if(! username){
            username = socket.id;       
        }
        socket.get('room', function(err, room){
            if (err) { throw err; }
            if(room) {
                socket.broadcast.to(room);          
            }
            socket.broadcast.emit('serverMessage', {name: username, data : content} );
            socket.broadcast.emit('serverMessage', 'test' );

        });
    });
});
```

My problem is at theses lines :

```
socket.broadcast.emit('serverMessage', {name: username, data : content} );
socket.broadcast.emit('serverMessage', 'test' );
```

With two socket.broadcast.emit, the second is broadcasted to everyone.

How comes that ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making the incorrect (though understandable) assumption that `socket.broadcast.to(room)` makes a lasting change to the internal state of the socket connection, so that any subsequent broadcasts are made to the specified room.  In reality, it only lasts for one `emit` before being reset.  The `to` method is meant to be chained to each `emit` call, like so:

```
        socket.broadcast.to(room).emit('serverMessage', {name: username, data : content});          
        socket.broadcast.to(room).emit('serverMessage', 'test' );
```

By default, every socket is joined to a room with an empty name, so if your intention is to broadcast to a specific room if it exists, and otherwise broadcast to everyone, then your code can be rewritten simply as:

```
    socket.get('room', function(err, room){
        if (err) { throw err; }
        // Default to the global room
        room = room || '';
        socket.broadcast.to(room).emit('serverMessage', {name: username, data : content} );            
        socket.broadcast.to(room).emit('serverMessage', 'test' );
    });
```

Comment: Ty, i tought afterall it could be something like that. Thanks!